# Collection won't store string

Tags: excel, vba

Since this morning I'm experiencing a weird behavior in VBA (Excel 2003).

Here's the code:

```
Sub TestCollection()

Dim i As Single, col As New Collection
Dim vArr(1 To 3) As String

'For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
'    vArr(i) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i)
'Next i

vArr(1) = "String 1"
vArr(2) = "String 2"
vArr(3) = "String 3"

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    Debug.Print vArr(i)
    col.Add i, vArr(i)
    Debug.Print col(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Now, I'd expect my collection to be filled with Item/Key pairs like (e.g. in the Locals window):

```
Item 1 -> "String 1"
Item 2 -> "String 2"
Item 3 -> "String 3"
```

but unfortunately I'm getting all items like:

```
Item 1 -> 1
Item 2 -> 2
Item 3 -> 3
```

Does anybody have a clue why the collection doesn't store the strings as a Key value?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly it looks like you want the value in `i` to be your key, instead of `String 1` for example. If so I'd recommend trying

```
vArr(1) = "String 1"
vArr(2) = "String 2"
vArr(3) = "String 3"

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    col.Add vArr(i), CStr(i)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, i) = col.Item(i)
Next i
```

Based on the example given a simpler method would be

```
vArr(1) = "String 1"
vArr(2) = "String 2"
vArr(3) = "String 3"

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    col.Add vArr(i)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, i) = col.Item(i)
Next i
```

where you just look items up by their index, but this may not work with your actual data.

Edit:
I can look up the column number based on the column name using this code:

```
Dim i As Single, col As New Collection
Dim vArr(1 To 3) As String

vArr(1) = "Column 1"
vArr(2) = "Column 2"
vArr(3) = "Column 3"

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    col.Add i, vArr(i)
Next i

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    Dim columnNumber As Integer
    columnNumber = col("Column 2")
    Sheet1.Cells(1, columnNumber).Value = "Found it"
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks huel, I might really have missed something here... the `col.Add vArr(i)` indeed works, but I wanted (needed) to control the Index number with `i`... though now I'm not sure it's possible anymore. An example of this can be found here: [link]( http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/12/26/populating-class-properties/) in the last code sample: `With tbl.HeaderRowRange: For i = 1 To .Count: col.Add i, .Columns(i): Next: End With`

Comment: Thanks for the link @Davide. It looks like they're using the column header as the key to look up the column index. In my first code block I used `col.Add vArr(i), CStr(i)`. It allows you to use a column index as key (after converting it to a string). Was this close to what you wanted?

Comment: exactly what I was trying to do, and can swear that the same code was working yesterday (weird enough). Unfortunately I need the column header as the String value is known, but the position of the column might change. Any other way to retrieve a collection Index using the corresponding Key? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Davide - Does my new edit work for you? I was able to get this to work on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation:
Add method on collection wants parameters in the order:  item, key  rather than: key, item.

Here's where I got that info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f26wd2e5.aspx

Comment: Thanks MiloNC, but that's exactly what I'm doing with `col.Add i, vArr(i)` where `i` is a number (i.e. index) and `vArr(i)` contains a string value (i.e. Key)

Comment: @Davide: I think your're NOT doing it in the order mentionned by MiloNC. Read your code again: for me it should be `col.Add vArr(i), i`

Comment: @iDevlop: I think I've understood MiloNC suggestion, but can't reverse the arguments as `i` is a Int/Single value and `vArr(i)` contains strings, therefore giving an Item Index of type String causes a Type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only edit I would make to your original code:

```
    col.Add vArr(i), CStr(vArr(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key must be a string, though the item can be an int, string, or probably any object.
If you want the keys to be simple integers, rather than "item 1" etc., just cast them, similar to Jerry Beaucaire's suggestion:

```
col.Add vArr(i), CStr(i)
```